Background courses for MSc in Finance
I'm a Mathematics bachelor student and next year I am going to pursue a 2-year MSc in Finance.
In this question, as a total beginner in Finance and more generally in Economics, I'd like to get information about what economical knowledge is essential for the above MSc from more experienced people. The fact that I've been admitted should mean that I will be able to catch up with the BSc essentials along the way, but I'd like to get a more precise view about what notions are generally required in those circumstances.
What courses in particular would give me a good preparation for what's on my way?
EDIT I honestly don't think that my Mathematical background is lacking, at least not for the beginning, and it's certainly broader and deeper than an Economics bachelor. I was more asking for essential Economics notions needed to start without always having to look back for missing definitions. It could also be interesting to find books about these basic courses written from a more Mathematical standpoint than the usual one.

I guess some sort of introduction into corporate finance would be useful. See e.g. Hillier et al. "Fundamentals of Corporate Finance".

Finance programs are extremely diverse. In some, people struggle with the basic calculus encountered in microeconomics, in others, people study complex stochastic processes. Without further information, it is hard to know what you need. (Similar things can be said about economics programs.)

@Giskard I updated my question in light of your answer.

Amanda: One question whose answer may shed some light is "what is your reasoning for going into economics ?". Is there some area or something specific that you like about it ? With a math bachelor's, you can definitely handle the math ( of course, at the higher levels, it can still be challenging )  but why may lead to more or different recommendations/suggestions.

@markleeds I could elaborate on that but in my view it's not pertinent: here I'm not asking how I should personally build my economical knowledge, but only about the thousand-time simpler matter of what BSc notions are essentials for a MSc in Finance.

it's kind of pertinent IMHO but that's fine. Say you told me that you liked time series and answering questions like "if the 10 year increases in the past month or so, can we say anything about the 1 year rate over the next month or so". Then, I'd recommend say a math stat book or econometrics text. But that's okay if you think it's not pertinent.
